# Python prime generator in one-line

Tags: python, math, integer, primes

I'm trying to create prime number generator in one-line of Python just as a fun exercise.

The following code works as expected, but it is too slow:

```
primes = lambda q: (i for i in xrange(1,q) if i not in [j*k for j in xrange(1,i) for k in xrange(1,i)])
for i in primes(10):
   print i,
```

So I I tried to do it by only checking up to the square-root of j and k:

```
primes = lambda q: (i for i in xrange(1,q) if i not in [j*k for j in xrange(1,int(round(math.sqrt(i)+1))) for k in xrange(1,int(round(math.sqrt(i)+1)))])
for i in primes(10):
   print i,
```

But it outputs: `2 3 5 6 7 8`

So there must be something wrong with my indices j and k, but I haven't got a clue.

Comment: If you can live with a non-oneliner, there is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567222/simple-prime-generator-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python- Sieve of Eratosthenes- Compact Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687296/python-sieve-of-eratosthenes-compact-python)

Comment: I was able to do it in two lines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9302299/5987

Comment: You could always take advantage of the fact that you CAN refer to the list currently being built inside of a list comprehension by using the expression `locals['_[1]']`.

Comment: This is the 3rd question I saw today that asked for an one-liner. Unless you’re Linus Torvalds, and designing Linux, I don’t understand the fad for cramming multiple LOC into a single line.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar what's meant by "single-line" is single-expression, I think.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's not the Sieve of Eratosthenes, even though it looks like it is. It is in fact much worse. The Sieve is the best algorithm for finding primes.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

**edit**: I've modified https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302299/711085 to be a one-liner (originally it was not the real Sieve, but now it is... probably...):

```
reduce( (lambda r,x: r-set(range(x**2,N,x)) if (x in r) else r), 
        range(2,N), set(range(2,N)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> primesUpTo(N): lambda N: reduce(...)
>>> primesUpTo(30)
{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
```

---

Sadly I think that while this would be efficient in a functional programming language, it might not be as efficient in python due to non-persistent (shared-state and immutable) data structures, and any sieve in python would need to use mutation to achieve comparable performance. We can still cram it into a one-liner if we desperately wanted to. But first...

Normal sieve:

```
>>> N = 100
>>> table = list(range(N))
>>> for i in range(2,int(N**0.5)+1):
...     if table[i]:
...         for mult in range(i**2,N,i):
...             table[mult] = False
... 
>>> primes = [p for p in table if p][1:]
>>> primes
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

We can now define and call anonymous functions on the same line, as well as the hack of `[...].__setitem__` to do inline mutation, and the hack of `... and foo` to evaluate `...` while returning `foo`:

```
>>> primesUpTo = lambda N: (lambda table: [[table.__setitem__(mult,False) for mult in range(i**2,N,i)] for i in range(2,int(N**0.5)+1) if table[i]] and [p for p in table if p][1:])(list(range(N)))
>>> primesUpTo(30)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

Proceed to cringe in horror, the one-liner expanded (oddly beautiful because you could almost directly translate the control flow, yet a terrible abuse of everything):

```
lambda N:
    (lambda table: 
        [[table.__setitem__(mult,False) for mult in range(i**2,N,i)] 
            for i in range(2,int(N**0.5)+1) if table[i]] 
        and [p for p in table if p][1:]
    )(list(range(N)))
```

This one-liner mutating version gave up at around 10<sup>8</sup> on my machine, while the original mutating version gave up at around 10<sup>9</sup>, running out of memory (oddly).

The original `reduce` version gave up at 10<sup>7</sup>. So perhaps it is not *that* inefficient after all (at least for numbers you can deal with on your computer).

**edit2** It seems you can abuse side-effects more concisely as:

```
reduce( (lambda r,x: (r.difference_update(range(x**2,N,x)) or r)
                     if (x in r) else r), 
        range(2,N), set(range(2,N)))
```

It gives up at around 10<sup>8</sup>, the same as the one-liner mutating version.

***edit3:*** This [runs at](http://ideone.com/Qyzjp) O(N) [empirical complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth), whereas without the `difference_update` it ran at [O(n^2.2) complexity](http://ideone.com/vZB5z).

Limiting the range that is reduced over, to the sqrt of the upper limit, and working [with odds only](http://ideone.com/gl1h9), both result in additional speed-ups (*2x* and *1.6x* correspondingly):

```
reduce( (lambda r,x: (r.difference_update(range(x*x,N,2*x)) or r)
                     if (x in r) else r), 
        range(3, int((N+1)**0.5+1), 2),
        set([2] + range(3,N,2)))
```

Comment: True, but this doesn't address the bug in his one-liner.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: he seemed explicitly a lot more concerned about the speed of his answer, which is directly related to the algorithm. Lookalike algorithms will begin to feel slow at maybe 10000+, and fail at 1000000+. Anyway, I've since edited my answer to give a real one-liner.

Comment: (if anyone is wondering why I keep editing/unediting, it's because it's extremely difficult to tell if an unorthodox implementation of the Sieve actually has a running time of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_complexity ; still even now making sure... sadly I think that while this would be efficient in a functional programming language, it is not efficient in python due to non-shared data structures, and any sieve in python would need to use mutation)

Comment: Actually better sieves exist for finding primes.  I believe that the current champ is the sieve of Atkins.  But Eratosthenes is good enough for virtually anything that you want.

Comment: After looking at this and my original two-liner, I don't think they are strictly implementing the Sieve since they remove multiples of numbers that have previously been eliminated as non-prime. I still congratulate you for a reasonable one-line prime number generator.

Comment: @MarkRansom: that's what I originally thought I noticed too (which caused me to flipflop edits back and forth). I think that even the regular sieve of Eratosthenes (and related sieves) have this issue. Nevertheless there is a significant optimization you can do which will avoid lots of re-crossing-out, though possibly not that much: you can cross off the numbers `range(i**2,N,i)` rather than `range(i*2,N,i)`, since i,2*i,3*i,...,(i-1)*i have already been eliminated.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that optimization and considered updating my two-liner but ultimately decided the question was stale and didn't warrant an edit.

Comment: @MarkRansom no, that is what the true Sieve of Eratosthenes does, it *does* remove multiples *several times* - once for each of the number's prime factors. That's because it doesn't "remove" them, when working with arrays - it *marks* them off. To remove an entry from array would break up the random access which is the key to sieve's efficiency - each *mark-off* takes O(1) time. With sets, it is probably O(log(size-of-set)), so worse a bit. And the improvement of crossing-off `range(i**2,N,2*i)` does warrant an edit, IMHO (esp. w/ sets). :) (notice, it's `2*i` when working with odds only).

Comment: @ninjagecko (your last comment) you mean `2i, 3i ... (i-1)*i` are eliminated. `i` better stay put. :) About that *optimization*, it *should* pay off handsomely when working with sets, *if* access complexity is not O(1) but rather O(log(size-of-set)). Then you do want to make as few crossings-off as possible. So start without evens and work with odds only: `reduce((lambda r,x: r-set(range(x*x,N,2*x))), range(3,int((N+1)**0.5+1),2), set([2]+range(3,N,2)))`.

Comment: @WillNess, What I meant is that a true Sieve of Eratosthenes only marks off multiples of the primes, not the multiples of every odd number. There are a goodly number more odd numbers than primes, making it unnecessarily slow.

Comment: ah, yes, of course. :) even with primes, many/some composites will be eliminated multiple times.

Comment: @MarkRansom: ack, I thought I had considered that, which was one of the reasons I suddenly removed the answer and put it back in. Guess my intuition was right. Thank you for pointing that out. Edited.

Comment: Try using `reduce( ..., range(2,int((N+1)**0.5+1)), ...)`, it should make for a *dramatic* improvement in speed. For some reason, trying to limit the work to odds only makes it run slower, **but**, limiting the range to a sqrt is still very much worth it, making [the code which runs](http://ideone.com/rQjKr) at **O(n^1.5)** instead of O(n^2.2) [with the full range](http://ideone.com/vZB5z), so that e.g. for primes up to 100,000 the former runs 62 times faster than the latter.

Comment: interesting, using difference_update brings down empirical complexity to below O(n) !! Still, limiting the range that is reduced over, to sqrt, makes for code that runs [twice faster](http://ideone.com/Qyzjp). But now, working with odds only pays off - it's [60% faster yet](http://ideone.com/gl1h9).

Comment: if you ever want to un-cw this answer, you can flag for mod assistance with that. I think you should -- the bulk of this answer is yours. I'm the only other editor here and I fully support this. cheers. :)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
def primes(x):
  return [i for i in range(2,x) if 0 not in [i%j for j in range(2,i)]]
```

Comment: You can rewrite this a bit shorter as:
def primes(x):
  return [i for i in range(2,x) if all([i%j for j in range(2,i)])]

Comment: you should add a case if the number is greater than 1 like below:

`[i for i in range(2,x) if ((0 not in [i%j for j in range(2,i)]) and i > 1)]`

Comment: why? it's covered by `i in range(2,x)`

Answer (score 3):

You can't check products of numbers only up to the square root to test for a prime. Look at 8- the square root of 8 is 2.8, so it will never try 4 * 2. (Indeed, the only numbers that *wouldn't* be seen as primes are square numbers).

ETA: Instead of trying all possible combinations of j and k, why not check if i is divisible by each j (using `i % j == 0`) up to the square root of j? This both takes less code and is much more efficient (though it is still *not nearly* as efficient as the Sieve of Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you wanted:

```
def primes (q) :
 # return (i for i in xrange(2,q) if i not in [j*k for j in xrange(1,i) for k in xrange(1,i)])
 # return (i for i in xrange(2,q) if i not in [j*k for j in xrange(1,i) for k in xrange(1,j+1)])
 # return (i for i in xrange(2,q) if i not in [j*k for j in xrange(1,i/2+1) for k in xrange(1,j+1)])

 return (i for i in xrange(2,q) if i not in [j*k for j in xrange(1,i/2+1) for k in xrange(1,min(j+1,i/j+1))])
```

In Haskell, the ranges are inclusive, so `primes(542)` is

```
[n | n<-[2..541], not $ elem n [j*k | j<-[1..n-1],     k<-[1..n-1]]]  --  25.66s
[n | n<-[2..541], not $ elem n [j*k | j<-[1..n-1],     k<-[1..j]]]    --  15.30s
[n | n<-[2..541], not $ elem n [j*k | j<-[1..n`div`2], k<-[1..j]]]    --   6.00s
                                                                      --   0.79s
[n | n<-[2..541], not $ elem n [j*k | j<-[1..n`div`2], k<-[1..min j (n`div`j)]]]
```

And actually, *`1*x == x`* so *1* isn't needed as a multiplier, thus it should be

```
[n | n<-[2..541], not $ elem n [j*k | j<-[2..n`div`2], k<-[2..min j (n`div`j)]]]
```

which takes only 0.59 seconds. Or, in Python,

```
def primes (q) :
 return (i for i in xrange(2,q) if i not in [j*k for j in xrange(2,i/2+1) for k in xrange(2,min(j+1,i/j+1))])
```

---

*update:* for some reason, `min j ...` doesn't make much of a difference, in Haskell at least. So the expression becomes simply

```
[n | n<-[2..541], not $ elem n [j*k | j<-[2..n`div`2], k<-[2..n`div`j]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

using comprehensions

```
[x for x in range(4, 1000) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are other great answers here, I wanted to include my version of it.

```
n = 1000
primes = [candidate for candidate in range(1, n) 
            if candidate not in [step * k
                   for step in range(2,n // 2 + 1) 
                   for k in range(2,n//x)]]
```

This has the running time complexity of *O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)*, because the sum of the first `n` terms of the harmonic series grows as `~ log n`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a oneliner based on the sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
primes = lambda N: (N>1)*[2] + [ p for s in [[1]*(N+1)]
                    for p in range(3,N+1,2) if s[p] 
                    and not s.__setitem__(slice(p,None,p),N//p*[0])]
```

It generates primes up to 1,000,000 in 0.097 sec on my laptop.

For primes up to 10^7   : 1.15 second,

For primes up to 5*10^7 : 6.43 seconds,

For primes up to 10^8   : 12.1 seconds,

For primes up to 5*10^8 : 67.1 seconds,

For primes up to 10^9   : 156 seconds (2.6 minutes)

For primes up to 10^10 : crashes the IDLE shell

Performance profile is essentially linear up to the point where memory management (virtual memory page pool swapping) starts interfering.  For example, 10^9 sieve flags take up 28G of memory which is more than the physical memory in my computer.

To reduce memory consumption (and improve performance by up to 15% on larger sets), the sieve can be limited to flagging only odd numbers given that 2 is handled separately:

```
primes = lambda N: (N>1)*[2] + [ p for s in [(N+1)//2*[1]]
                   for i,p in enumerate(range(3,N+1,2)) if s[i] 
                   and not s.__setitem__(slice(i,None,p),
                                         (len(s)-i+p-1)//p*[0])]
```

Comment: this can probably be made to run faster by starting the slice from `p*p` and thus stopping the sieving at the smallest `p` such that `p*p > N`. and special-casing the `2` and using the `2*p` step in the slice.

Comment: are you sure `p` reaches to `N` in the resulting array now? (I don't know Python very much, myself).  IOW, what is the length of `primes(541)`? it should be 100.

Comment: Yea that last change broke it (my bad).  I ended up going back to my original answer.  The additional computations needed to optimize the zero assignments actually made it slower. Low level slice assignments (even doing twice the number) are much faster than the extra Python code needed to figure out the slice size.

Comment: yeah I had a suspicion but was hoping there could be a way. :)

Comment: turns out saving the `p*p` and `p*2` in local variables helps to make it faster than the one in this answer, [by about 20%](https://ideone.com/7RTBKj). but there's no complexity improvement, only the constant factor (just as the theory says). cheers, :)

Comment: How did you measure those time improvements ? When I compare the original and your improved version I find yours to be 20-25% slower. (i'm using Python 3.7 though)

Comment: I ran that ideone entry that I linked. changing `primes` to `primes2` in the statement  `print( len(primes( 20000000)))` at the bottom of the code, it runs at ~20% shorter time both for 2M and 1M. it says on the ideone page that it runs "python  3.9.5". it doesn't really matter, since there's no algorithmic (i.e. complexity) improvement, and the constant factor is very close to 1.0 (either 0.8 or 1.2); just a curiosity.

Comment: I'm using `timeit` for precise time measurement (of only the executed function).  I get `timeit(lambda: primes(20000000),number=10)/10` = 2.34, and `timeit(lambda: primes2(20000000),number=10)/10` = 2.71

Comment: may be it's due to the difference of the versions.

Comment: Surprisingly, it is indeed a difference of version. I tried on a Pyhton 3.9.2 version I had installed for another project and I did get similar improvements as what you observed (primes:2.48 vs primes2:1.89).  I never realized that there were such performance differences between 3.x versions.  TIL, I will consider moving my stuff to a more recent Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPrime(n):
    return all(n % d for d in range(2, int(n**.5)+1))

primes = {n for n in range(2, 100) if isPrime(n)}
```

This can be compressed to one line if needed:

```
primes = {n for n in range(2, 100) if all(n % d for d in range(2,int(n**.5)+1))}
```

Where `{` genexp `}` generates a set: duplicates are only stored once.

`all()` ensures that none of the values are `False` **(or `0`)**; in this case that ensures that none of the numbers below the number we're testing are factors, in which case the number is prime.

And we add 1 to the end of the range because `range()` is non-inclusive.

We check all factors up to the square root of the number for efficiency: If no numbers below sqrt(n) are factors, no numbers above sqrt(n) are factors, because factors always come in pairs.

For further efficiency we would use Eratosthenes algorithm (for small `n`) where you first eliminate all factors of 2, then all factors of 3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

here is a one line code to do it:

```
print((lambda n:[i for i in range(2, n) if ["A7A" for j in range(2, i) if i%j==0]==[]])(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way which is not a one-liner but is more efficient. The positive side is that every time you only check for previously found prime numbers rather than looking into all values in range(n):

```
def prime(n):
    pm_list = [2]
    for i in range(3,n+1):
        pm_arr = np.array(pm_list)
        if any(i // pm_arr == i / pm_arr) == False:
            pm_list.append(i)
    return pm_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should print a list of all numbers below the value 'limit'.

```
primes = lambda limit: [num for num in range(2, limit) if num > 1 and (num == 2 or num % 2 != 0) and all(num % divisor != 0 for divisor in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2))]

print(primes(30))
```

Answer (score -1):

My code is (for numbers in range(2,50)):

```py
import operator

[len(x) for x in list(map(lambda x: [operator.mod(len(range(1,x)), z) for z in range(1,x)], [item for item in range(2,50)])) if x.count(0) == 2]
```

Comment: Hi there, could you formulate your statement into a question?
Are you trying to ask how to make a python prime number generator in one line?

Comment: @YacineMahdid this post is an answer, not a question