# Why is my Sieve of Erasthotenes not working? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

This is my code. I'm trying to make an efficient but simple Sieve of Erasthotenes but when I run the program it just keeps returning integers, however large i put the range. This is in python 3.

```
lyst = []
for i in range(2, 100):
    print(i)
    lyst.append(i)
count = 2
index = 1
for x in lyst:
    print(str(index) + " : " + str(count))
    if x%count == 0 and x != count:
        lyst.remove(x) #removing all multiples of count
    if max(lyst) == count: #breaks loop if count is the largest prime
        break
    else:
        count = lyst[lyst.index(count)+1] #turns count into next prime
    index += 1 #this is just for me to track how many primes i've found
```

Comment: Why do you compare `count == lyst...`? (And throw away the result.)

Comment: I'm trying to turn count into the next prime, i.e the next greatest one in the list. Trying to replicate what it says on wikipedia for the sieve:

Comment: you do realize that you're removing all x's ... not only multiples .. ?

Comment: @Noctis sorry? I do not see how I am doing that. I thought i put in the and operator and those conditions to only eliminate multiples

Comment: `==` is a *comparison*, not an assignment. You didn't do `count == 2` either.

Comment: == donot change count , this statement is useless

Comment: because the logic should be : take a number, remove all it's multiples from the list, take the next number, rinse and repeat, until you're out of numbers. where in your code do you remove the multiples ? you need a second loop, which you obviously don't have.

Comment: But @Noctis, am i not removing all the multiples from my code here? if x%count == 0 and x != count:
        lyst.remove(x)

Comment: nope, that is for the the x you're working on ... so, for each element of the list ...(which you misspelled as lyst, but let's not be petty). what you want, is after taking a number, add it to your primes, and remove all it's duplicates

Comment: No the reason I "misspelt" list as lyst is because I like it as my listname. But thanks anyway

Comment: so many fine answers, yet you have not commented on any ... :(

Answer (score 1):

The value for *x* and *count* will always have the same value:

- they start out like that with value 2
- for this reason the `remove` will not be executed
- at the end of the iteration *count* will be the next value from the list, which is exactly what *x* will be at the start of the next iteration

Conclusion: they have the same value at the start of each iteration, and therefore the `if` condition is never satisfied.

Secondly, the sieve of Erasthotenes is not supposed to remove elements from the sieve, but to mark certain values as non-prime. Its power is in keeping the values at their original index, so `.remove()` is not really supposed to occur in a plain sieve algorithm.

For inspiration on finding a correct implementation, you can look at several answers:

- [Sieve of Eratosthenes - Finding Primes Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3941967/5459839)
- [A Fast Prime Number Sieve in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997575/5459839)
- [Python- Sieve of Eratosthenes- Compact Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6687958/5459839)
- ... and a whole lot more.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it ... have a look at the inner loop that removes the multiples:

```
lyst = []
max = 100 # because ... you know, variables. ...
for i in range(2, max):
    lyst.append(i)
count = 2
index = 1
for x in lyst:
    print(str(index) + " : " + str(x)) # x is a prime number, so print it
    for y in lyst:
        if y>x and y%x == 0:
            lyst.remove(y)

    index += 1 #this is just for me to track how many primes i've found
print(index) # how many did we find
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a mix of your code and the [wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) :

```
n = 100
lyst = range(2, n)
for p in lyst:
    if not p:
        continue
    for i in range(2*p,n,p):
      lyst[i-2] = None
print [p for p in lyst if p]
#=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: Wikipedia description goes to great lengths repeating over and over that the multiples are to be generated at equal increments (i.e. by repeated additions), ***not*** found by any divisibility tests.

Comment: @WillNess : Excellent comment, thanks. It's often harder to modify an existing script than starting from scratch. I updated the method.

Comment: glad to be of help. :)